# How to use <br/> in string to put string in new line?

Tags: reactjs

I was creating React project and here is the component that I want to ensure that 
 is put inside a string.

```
<InfoIcon
 tooltip={`${hints.todoHint} <br/> ${hints.inProgressHint} <br/> ${hints.doneHint}`}
 />
```

but it is not working since br/ is literally rendered like br/

Comment: you can't have it like this. because the props are considered as a value rather than html elements. You have to modify the the code of InfoIcon component order to get this done.

Comment: @Wertu Did that post solved your problem? Kindly inform me if you have further questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, material-ui **tooltip** allows you to use ANY kind of HTML content. => refer to official document [customized tooltiops](https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#customized-tooltips)

This means you can use normal `<div>` and `<Typography />`, and any other styled elements to handle multi-line content.

The only thing you need to do is pass the content to props `title` => refer to document of [tooltip api](https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/)

```
import {
  Tooltip,
  Typography
} from '@material-ui/core';

<Tooltip
  title={ // customized content here via props `title`
    <>
      <div>Seperate line</div>
      <Typography>Seperate line</Typography>
    </>
  }
>
  <IconButton aria-label="delete">
    <InfoIcon /> // You can use your original icon here
  </IconButton>
</Tooltip>
```

Watch it online: https://stackblitz.com/run

[image]

---

You can find related question here: [How to make line break for ToolTip titles in Material-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598842/how-to-make-line-break-for-tooltip-titles-in-material-ui/60599256#60599256)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to convert `tooltip` in to three props and add `<br />` in the `InfoIcon` component. For example `InfoIcon` component can be

```
const InfoIcon = ({ todoHint, inProgressHint, doneHint }) => (
  <div>
    {todoHint}
    <br />
    {inProgressHint}
    <br />
    {doneHint}
  </div>
);
// Using Info Icon
<InfoIcon todoHint={todoHint} inProgressHint={inProgressHint} doneHint={doneHint} />
```

Other option is to send tooltip as follows

```
const tooltip = (
  <div>
    {hints.todoHint}
    <br />
    {hints.inProgressHint}
    <br />
    {hints.doneHint}
  </div>
)
<InfoIcon tooltip={tooltip} />
```

Comment: You should use tooltip prop in `InfoIcon` as e.g. `<div>{tooltip}</div>`